Where to pass user_data in this type of method of code
Normally I used this method of coding:
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct AppData appData; // personal structure
  GtkApplication *app;
  gint status;

  app = gtk_application_new (PROGRAM_ID, G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);  
  g_signal_connect (app, "startup", G_CALLBACK (cb_startup), &appData);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (cb_activate), &appData);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}

I'm trying to adapt my code like the trivial example:

include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "exampleapp.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct AppData appData; // personal structure
  return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (example_app_new ()), argc, argv);
}

My question is: how can I pass my personal structure in the above style code?

Have a look at the 2nd example in your link and convert it to a class type structure.  Once you've done that you can create a new class which inherits from that and adds your own personal information.

@cup: seems that gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child is need it when is used UI file. I see the example, but for me it's to hard to follow and messy for a single task, maybe I'll just back to my old style code.

I think that the first variant can be taken in a simple program.
It is also given as an example.
The second variant is certainly useful for more complex programs.
I rebuilt the example mentioned in the question so that it would also work in the second variant.
main-example.c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "exampleapp.h"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  static appData data;
   appData *data_ptr = &data;
   data_ptr->name = "Holger";
   data_ptr->value = 11;

  return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (example_app_new (data_ptr)), argc, argv);
}

exampleapp.h
#pragma once

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define EXAMPLE_APP_TYPE (example_app_get_type ())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (ExampleApp, example_app, EXAMPLE, APP, GtkApplication)

   typedef struct AppData
   {
           char *name;
           int  value;
   } appData; // personal structure

ExampleApp     *example_app_new         (appData *data);

exampleapp.c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "exampleapp.h"

struct _ExampleApp
{
  GtkApplication parent;
  appData *data; 
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE(ExampleApp, example_app, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION);

static void
example_app_init (ExampleApp *app)
{
}

static void
example_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
  GtkWidget  *win;

  g_print ("Name = %s\n",EXAMPLE_APP(app)->data->name);
  g_print ("Value = %d\n",EXAMPLE_APP(app)->data->value);

  win = gtk_application_window_new(GTK_APPLICATION(app));
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}

static void
example_app_open (GApplication  *app,
                  GFile        **files,
                  int            n_files,
                  const char    *hint)
{
}

static void
example_app_class_init (ExampleAppClass *class)
{
  G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class)->activate = example_app_activate;
  G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class)->open = example_app_open;
}

ExampleApp *
example_app_new (appData *data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window =  g_object_new (EXAMPLE_APP_TYPE,
                       "application-id", "org.gtk.exampleapp",
                       "flags", G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN,
                       NULL);
  EXAMPLE_APP(window)->data = data;     

  return EXAMPLE_APP(window);
}

I do not necessarily want to say whether this is a good option.
But it shows the principle of how it could be realized.
Greetings

Thanks. This saves extra code lines and does the job expected.
